# load words from file and make a list of that

Tags: python

My idea is to load words from a directory (contains A Words.txt- Z Words.txt) and copy it into a list. The below code works, but adds `"\n"` at the end of each word (example `["apple\n", "abort\n"]`); can anybody suggest a way to fix it?

```
from io import *
import string

def load_words(base_dir):
words = []
for i in string.uppercase:
    location = base_dir+"\\"+i+" Words.txt"
    with open(location, "rb+") as f:
        words += f.readlines()
return words
```

Comment: as a side note.. please consider using os.path.join for building paths, e.g. location = join(base_dir, i + " Words.txt") it has the advantage of being portable to OS's that use / as the separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```
from io import *
import string

def load_words(base_dir):
words = []
for i in string.uppercase:
    location = base_dir+"\\"+i+" Words.txt"
    with open(location, "rb+") as f:
        for i in f.readlines():
            words.append(i.strip())
return words
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly strip newlines using [`str.rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.rstrip):

```
def load_words(base_dir):
    words = []
    for i in string.uppercase:
        location = base_dir+"\\"+i+" Words.txt"
        with open(location, "rb+") as f:
            for line in f:                      # <---------
                words.append(line.rstrip())     # <---------
            # OR words.extend(line.rstrip() for line in f)
    return words
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
words += f.readlines()
```

to :

```
words += [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
```

[strip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes trailing and leading whitespace charachters.